# For the function $g(x) = 8x^2 - x + 4$, at what tangent point is the instantaneous rate of change equal to $-1$?

Tags: calculus

It is a multiple-choice question with the options of:

a) $(1,11)$

b) $(-1,13)$

c) $(0,4)$

d) $(2,34)$

Really struggling with how to approach this one. This style of question isn't covered at all in my course content up to this point and I've had a hard time finding similar questions through Google search. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT**
\begin{align*}
y = 8x^{2} - x + 4 \Longrightarrow y^{\prime} = 16x - 1 = -1 \Longrightarrow x = 0
\end{align*}